# Compiling Vim 7.4 with GUI support on Fedora 20

Tags: vim, fedora, gvim, gnome3

I've installed the following dependencies before trying to compile Vim 7.4 from source on Fedora 20 (Default Gnome). I've removed the vim-enhanced package via yum before proceeding:

```
yum install ncurses-libs gnome-libs-devel libgnomeui-devel
    gtk2-devel libbonoboui-devel libX11-devel libXpm-devel
    libXt-devel python-devel ruby-devel cairo-devel
```

However, when I try to do something like:

```
./configure --with-features=huge --enable-rubyinterp
            --enable-python3interp --enable-gui=gnome2
            --enable-cscope --prefix=/usr/local --with-x=yes | grep gui
```

I get the following during the configuration step:

```
checking --enable-gui argument... no GUI support
```

I've installed all the dependencies that I know of. I've searched online, and cannot find any references to solve this problem. Is there a dependency that I'm missing?

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question, but unless you have a particular reason for not letting Vim auto-configure the GUI support, I would leave out the `--enable-gui=gnome2` option. Also, the default prefix is /usr/local, so you don't need that, and with `--with-features=huge`, you don't need `--with-x`, either.

Comment: Actually, I tried doing that (even --enable-gui=auto). I added things like --with-x as a desperate attempt to get it to work.

Comment: Did you check the auto/config.log file?

Comment: Yes, I did. I didn't find anything useful there. However, I just re-downloaded the mercurial repository and this time, it worked. I might have added new dependencies in between, but it only started working on a fresh repo checkout.